# Failed to fetch when building docker

Tags: apt, 18.04, docker

I'm pretty new to linux env and I'm trying to build a docker with the following command:

> docker-compose up --build

but I'm getting this error:

> W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
> ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update    && apt-get install -y vim zlib1g-dev zlibc zlib1g libicu-dev g++ locales libmemcached-dev   libxml2-dev php5-mysql  && pecl install memcached-2.2.0' returned a non-zero code: 100

I tried to run:

> apt-get update
>
> apt-get upgrade

And they run fine without any errors, but my build keeps showing this error.

I'm using ubuntu 18.04.